# Historical origins of the idea that information cannot travel faster than light

Tags: relativity-theory, einstein

Is there a good book or other reference that discusses the historical origins of the principle that not even information can travel faster than the speed of light? In my understanding the main reason why such superluminal signaling is usually considered impossible is that this would violate causality in the context of special relativity. What were the first scientific papers discussing such causality violations?

Comment: This comes from the physics of causality in special relativity since Einstein's 1905 paper. The exact terminology might have shifted but it starts there.

Comment: @Mauricio Thanks for your comment. I'm somewhat familiar with Einstein's original paper, and even though it shows that no subluminal particle can be accelerated to superluminal speeds, and that the relativistic addition of subluminal velocities yields again a subluminal velocity, this does not immediately lead to the strict impossibility of superluminal particles (i.e. tachyons), let alone superluminal signaling in general. Causality arguments are often used to argue against them, however. But I don't think Einstein does. I'm specifically looking for papers/books that cover such possibilities

Comment: You can take a look at the [tachyonic antitelephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone). Already by 1907 Einstein was considering the problem of faster-than-light communications so this is as early as you can get.

Comment: @Mauricio great thanks!

Comment: You seem to be overthinking it. The reason superluminal communication is impossible under relativity is plainly that no information carrier can travel faster than light. One does not need to think of any causality violations to conclude *that* (although they do, of course, follow).

Comment: @Conifold It does not follow directly from special relativity that no information carrier can travel faster than light. That's of course why Einstein gave the tachyonic antitelephone argument in his 1907 paper advocated above by Mauricio

Comment: Such thought experiments illustrate how superluminal speeds lead to "time travel". They are not needed to merely show that matter/energy are subluminal in SR. It does follow directly from the [relativistic mass formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Relativistic_mass), which Einstein derived already in 1905. "Tachyons" must have imaginary mass to satisfy relativity equations, which is non-sensical except to sci-fi enthusiasts.

Comment: @Conifold I agree that it is tempting to immediately draw this conclusion, but imaginary mass is not a priori a problem.

Comment: At least it is not immediately obvious to me that such particles could not exist. Let's put it that way. ;) And I know a lot of my colleagues agree. I believe later people have provided good arguments why they probably do not exists, and I'm interested in this history. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: In that sense, time travel is not *a priori* a problem either, no more than imaginary mass. General relativity allows it and physicists even came up with wormhole scenarios for it just as they did with tachyons. Causality violations do not lead to paradoxes without some sort of "free will" assumptions.

Comment: Completely agree